# Can selenium be a web service?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm really new to Selenium. I took a look at Selenium IDE and it was very easy to use but when I tried learning Selenium WebDriver but I'm having a hard time looking for good material to learn from. The way I understand this is that I has to be used with a programming language? is this correct? if not, I would prefer to use WebDriver with PHP since I'm more familiar with it. I made some research and I found that Selenium is mostly used with PHP testing frameworks but I dont want to use it with a testing framework since I'm not doing any testing. Is there anyway to use selenium with PHP only?

That being said, I would really like to know if it is possible for selenium to a web service, me and my team plan to have this as as service in the website we are hosting.

Let's say for example, a customer request to automate a task, like to post ads on a e-commerce website using a CSV and some images. There would be some kind of form for the customer to submit their CSV file and images. And the data in the CSV would be used as materials for the ads. We make the script for this specific request, is it possible to host the script from the server and run the script from there every time the costumer want to automate the task again?

Or can the selenium only be executed from the customers computer? If so, how can the customer start the script and to open the server to get the script? What should be installed in the customers computer? A .bat file would probably one solution but I am not sure how it can access the script in the server or what files are needed to install for that matter.

I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, we can not use it as you expected it for.
if you are ready to write script you can write any webservice for the same task as selenium is not for the purpose you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that the script cannot be hosted in the server and retrieved from the server?

Comment: i mean this is not possible with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Could you please explain why?